# ¿Existe un verbo para "hablar en voz alta"?

Tags: verbos, significado, solicitud-de-término

Tuve una vez un profesor de teatro que decía que no era lo mismo "hablar en voz alta" que "gritar", y que los actores de teatro tienen que aprender a hablar en voz lo suficientemente alta como para que todo el público se entere del diálogo, pero sin llegar al grito.

Si buscamos en el diccionario, *[gritar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=JYq8Ucq)* es "dar un grito", y *[grito](http://dle.rae.es/?id=JYy1mZh)* es "voz muy esforzada y levantada". Estoy buscando una palabra que solo contenga la parte de "levantada", es decir, hablar en voz alta, pero sin esforzar la voz, sin la parte de llegar a romper el grito. Se me ocurrió en principio *[vociferar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=c09iOW2)*: "vocear o dar grandes voces". Sin embargo, tanto esta definición como la de *[vocear](http://dle.rae.es/?id=bzchpMZ)* usan la palabra *voces*, que es sinónimo de *grito* (la acepción de *[voz](http://dle.rae.es/?id=c4LfLPC)* que está marcada como usada más en plural).

¿Qué verbo existe pues en español para esta acción?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Para el caso concreto del teatro, la expresión que buscas es **proyectar la voz**.

Este es el término que se usa tanto en teatro como en canto para hacer referencia a la técnica vocal que hay que emplear para elevar la voz, sin dañar la garganta, y de forma que alcance a todo el auditorio.

Se basa en la respiración diafragmática, en el empleo de la cavidad bucal como amplificador de la voz, y de los diferentes "huecos" de la cara (senos nasales, temporales) como resonadores naturales.

Es una expresión específica de la oratoria y el canto, pero si nos guiamos por lo que dice la RAE, aun así, tiene sentido. En el DLE, tenemos en la primera acepción de [*proyectar*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=UV1NQcU):

> 1. tr. Lanzar, dirigir hacia delante o a distancia.

Que es aplicable a lo que comentaba más arriba, ya que cuando se *proyecta la voz*, la imagen mental que se debe tener es la de un chorro de voz que sale de nuestra boca y que tiene que dirigirse de forma constante, estable y firme hacia un punto en la distancia.

Una fuente (más allá de mi propia experiencia): [Cómo proyectar tu voz](https://es.wikihow.com/proyectar-tu-voz)

Comment: También *proyectar* se entiende con un poquito de contexto.

Answer (score 8):

No obstante la [respuesta de @Alicia](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/23092/13628), que es la que considero correcta...

Dado que indicas que estás *"buscando una palabra"*, una palabra te propongo:

> **[declamar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=BxW0PUW#5G4c7VL)**
>
> 1. intr. Hablar en público.
>     4. intr. **Recitar la prosa o el verso con entonación**, ademanes y gestos **adecuados**. U. t. c. tr.

Parte de recitar con entonación adecuada es, precisamente, el saber *proyectar la voz* para que sea oída tanto en primera fila como en el gallinero.
Además, por su primera acepción de "hablar en público", **declamar** se asocia de manera natural con hablar en voz alta.

Answer (score 2):

Siguiendo el razonamiento de @walen también podríamos usar:

> **[recitar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=VRvloDZ)**.
>
> 1. tr. Referir, contar o decir en voz alta un discurso u oración.
> 2. tr. Decir o pronunciar de memoria y en voz alta versos, discursos, etc.

Recitar se define claramente como *hablar en voz alta* y puede usarse para hablar en público o en privado indistintamente.

Comment: Creo que aquí *en voz alta* se utiliza por oposición a *en voz baja* o incluso *mentalmente*. No creo que la palabra *recitar* dé idea de que la voz sea especialmente alta.

Comment: @Gorpik Sí, es posible. Aunque *declamar* y *recitar* son básicamente sinónimos aunque tengan alguna ligera diferencia. Creo que *recitar* es una opción igual de válida.